# Retrieve Value From Json array by knowing a field value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json array that look like,

```
0: {NodeID:1, Node_Location:30,0,60,30, Node_CurrentURL:http://google.com, Node_Title:google,Node_Amount: 10}
1: {NodeID:2, Node_Location:90,90,160,30, Node_CurrentURL:http://gmail.com, Node_Title:gmail,Node_Amount: 30}
2: {NodeID:3, Node_Location:180,160,260,30, Node_CurrentURL:http://asp.net, Node_Title:asp,Node_Amount: 40}
```

My json array is received from webapi and want to display over client side.

How  i retrieve Node_Amount by knowing NodeID?
Help me please, 
Thanks.

Comment: If you can rely on the `NodeID` always being one higher than the array index you could do `yourObject[knownId-1].Node_Amount`. Except that the data you show above is not in a valid JSON format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$.each(jsonarray, function(index, value)
{
    if (value.NodeID == specificnodeid)
    {
        //store it some place safe
        return;
        //or alternatively you can return the value as
        // return value;
    }
});
```

Comment: `return value` wouldn't return the value when used from a `$.each()` callback. (I mean, technically it _would_ return the value back to jQuery, but jQuery doesn't pass it on to your code.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is the output model of the parsed json array:

```
var json = {
  0: {
    NodeID: 1,
    Node_Location: [],
    Node_CurrentURL: '',
    Node_Title: '',
    Node_Amount: 10
  },
  1: {
    NodeID: 2,
    Node_Location: [],
    Node_CurrentURL: '',
    Node_Title: '',
    Node_Amount: 30
  }
};
```

If you know the `NodeID` is the same as the root object plus one, and you want to get the `Node_Amount` knowing the id number it may be as simple as this:

```
var id = 1;
var amount = json[String(id-1)].Node_Amount; // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you preprocess the array, let's call it `NodeArray`,

```
var NodeArray = [{
  NodeID: 1,
  Node_Location: [30, 0, 60, 30],
  Node_CurrentURL: "http://google.com",
  Node_Title: "google", 
  Node_Amount: 10
}];
```

into an associative array `Nodes` with key bound to `NodeID`

```
var Nodes = {};
for (var i = 0; i < NodeArray.length; i++) {
  Nodes[NodeArray[i].NodeID] = NodeArray[i];
}
```

then you can easily access any element in `Nodes` by `NodeID` (`Nodes[NodeID]`.)

```
console.log(Nodes[1]);
// {NodeID:1, Node_Location:[30,0,60,30], Node_CurrentURL:"http://google.com", Node_Title:"google", Node_Amount:10}
```

This merely relies in the fact that `NodeID` is unique and it is present.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is'nt really valid, I'm guessing the strings are quoted etc. and it really looks like:

```
var obj = {
    0: {NodeID:1, Node_Location:'30,0,60,30', Node_CurrentURL:'http://google.com', Node_Title:'google',Node_Amount: 10},
    1: {NodeID:2, Node_Location:'90,90,160,30', Node_CurrentURL:'http://gmail.com', Node_Title:'gmail',Node_Amount: 30},
    2: {NodeID:3, Node_Location:'180,160,260,30', Node_CurrentURL:'http://asp.net', Node_Title:'asp',Node_Amount: 40}
       };
```

And you can access values by doing:

```
var URL = obj[0].Node_CurrentURL;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jCsyC/)